# MongoDB - using $nin on another field

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.6.7 and I am trying to run the following query

```
Categories.find({'_id': { $nin: ancestors }})
```

Where the Categories collection is exactly like that used in MongoDB docs manual (model tree structures with ancestors array). Ex:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", ancestors: [ "Books", "Programming", "Databases" ], parent: "Databases" } )
```

but I am not getting any results, so I was wondering if it is possible to get all documents in the Categories collection which are not included in the ancestors array field of any document... in other words Categories that have no child categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need the set of all of the categories inside `ancestors` in your `categories` collection. If you have this list, then you can run a simple query:

```
> var ancestors = [ "Books", "Programming", "Databases" ];
> db.categories.find({ "_id" : { "$nin" : ancestors }});
```

If you don't have that `ancestors` set, then you can get it using aggregation.

```
> db.categories.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$ancestors" },
    { "$group":
        {
            "_id": null,
            "ancestors": { "$addToSet": "$ancestors" }
        }
    }
]);
{ "_id" : null, "ancestors" : [ "Databases", "Programming", "Books" ] }
```

You can also get this array using `distinct()`.

```
> db.categories.distinct("ancestors");
[ "Books", "Databases", "Programming" ]
```

With that result you can then run the original query.